# Using multiple SQL statements in EF migration - how to use GO to run in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am renaming some columns using EF6 migrations, and need to update several functions, views and stored procedures which use the columns. I want to add these as separate `Sql()` calls within different private methods so the overall migration is easier to read.

When I do this, I can run the migration using `update-database` without any problems, but if I generate scripts (using `update-database -script`) the script doesn't run fully because `'ALTER FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.`.

I have tried putting a `GO` at the end of each `Sql()` statement, but when EF generates the script it removes the `GO`. If I try with two of them (see below), EF gives the error `The argument 'sql' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.`

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION myFunc
...
GO
GO
```

I want to be able to run the migration through EF, or by generating a script, and for both to work without needing to change any configuration or manually modify the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an odd fix to this problem:

```
GO
--any arbitrary comment here
GO
```

My guess is that EF will remove `GO` from the end of a `Sql()` call:

```cs
Sql(@"
--actual SQL here
GO");
```

Including the arbitrary comment seems to mean that only the final `GO` is removed, but the initial one is kept. This works for me regardless of whether I run the migration through EF or generate a script to run in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue and found that Tim's "Arbitrary Comment" does resolve it.  Also, removing the extra GO from the SQL being executed works as well.  I believe that underlying provider is parsing the SQL into blocks to execute based on the GO statements and when it reads the second repeating GO there is no preceeding SQL so the error occurs.

**Error SQL Script**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[GetData] 
GO 
GO 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetData] .... <some SP code here>
GO
```

**Functioning SQL Script**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[GetData] 
GO 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetData] .... <some SP code here>
GO
```

Comment: That sounds useful, thanks. Which `GO` did you remove? i.e. do you have `Sql(@"--real SQL GO --arbitrary comment")` or `Sql(@"--real SQL --arbitrary comment GO")`?

Comment: @Tim I had something similar to this, `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[GetData] GO GO ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetData] .... GO` that was causing an error.  I simply removed the second GO.  My SQL file now looks like this and EF code first runs it without issues `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[GetData] GO ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetData] .... GO`